# Standardizing data values

Tags: normalization, standardization

I see an example for standardizing data value [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-step-by-step-introduction-to-pca-c0d78e26a0dd). For better illustration, the table is shown below

[image]

I did the same thing in excel and as you can see, the results are different.

[image]

For mean and variance, I used AVERAGE and VAR formulas, respectively in Excel. The standardized values are calculated as:

```
0  ->  (0-2.5)/3.5 = -0.714
...
```

What is wrong then?

Comment: Use the [standard deviation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/398116/930) (the $\sigma_x$ in the post you refer to) instead of the variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value $3.5$ is calculated using the sample variance formula.

You need to use the population standard deviation formula:
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{n}}
\end{equation}

The population standard deviation is $\sqrt{2.916667}$. Standardizing using this value will yield the desired results.
\begin{equation}
\frac{0-2.5}{\sqrt{2.916667}} \approx -1.4638501
\end{equation}

Using R we can replicate the results from your example:

```
x = c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
s1 = sum((x-mean(x))^2)/6
xs = (x-mean(x))/sqrt(s1)
data.frame(x, xs= round(xs,2))
```

Output:

```
 x    xs
 0 -1.46
 1 -0.88
 2 -0.29
 3  0.29
 4  0.88
 5  1.46
```

Comment: In Excel, I see STDEV, STDEV.P, STDEV.S and some other forms. Doe sit matter which one to use?

Comment: Yes it does, the sample and population standard deviation use different denominator $n-1$ vs $n$, respectively. STDEVP is the function you want to use - this will use $n$